# Java error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Student[]

Tags: java

I don't know how do I tackle this compilation error.

my code is

```
public ArrayList<Student> SortOnCGPA(ArrayList<Student> stu){        
        Student sorStu[] = stu.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(sorStu, new StuDescend());
        stu = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sorStu));
        return stu;
    }
```

and the error is:

```
JavaPQ.java:23: error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Student[]
        Student sorStu[] = stu.toArray();
                                      ^
Note: JavaPQ.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

I know that the "toArray()" method will return an array of type Object.
I don't know how to typecast it to Student[] or any alternative solution.
Thanks for for your help.

I used a loop to solve my problem

```
public ArrayList<Student> SortOnCGPA(ArrayList<Student> stu){        
        Student sorStu[] =new Student[stu.size()];
        Iterator it = stu.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            sorStu[i] = new Student((Student)it.next());
            i++;
        }
        Arrays.sort(sorStu, new StuDescend());
        stu = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sorStu));
        return stu;
    }
```

But I wanted to know how do I use the ".toArray()" method of the collections framework.

Comment: `Student sorStu[] = stu.toArray(new Student[stu.size()]);`

Comment: Why are you converting to an array anyway? What's wrong with `List.sort`? Or `stu.stream().sorted(new StuDescend()).collect(toList())`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you may be interested in [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). TL;DR: `new Student[0]` was found to be better.

Comment: or `Collections.sort(stu, new StuDescend());`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko (`Collections.sort` delegates to `List.sort`)

Comment: By using toArray() JVM will not blindly know your type of array.  So you need to pass your typed array e.g. Student[] stdArr = new Student[stu.size()]; . Then it will create your desired output.